# Next Iterator method for associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I want to use an associative array with the PHP iterator:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php

is it possible?

I defined these methods:

```
  public function rewind(){    
    reset($this->_arr);
    $this->_position = key($this->_arr);
  }

  public function current(){    
    return $this->_arr[$this->_position];
  }

  public function key(){
    return $this->_position;
  }

  public function next(){    
    ++$this->_position;
  }

  public function valid(){    
    return isset($this->_arr[$this->_position]);
  }
```

the problem is it doesn't iterate correctly. I only get one element.

I think it's because of the `++$this->_position` code in the next() method which doesn't have any effect because _position is a string (key of the associative array).

so how can I go to the next element of this type of array?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you just using an [ArrayIterator](http://us.php.net/arrayiterator)?

Comment: Can you please show more of your code? That would be a) the part where you say `class XYZ implements Iterator` b) the part where you (try to) use it.

Comment: "I defined these methods" -- it is called "copy-pasted as-is from documentation" ;-)

Comment: If this is for a class holding an array, consider implementing `IteratorAggregate` and return an `ArrayIterator` for that array in `getIterator`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
function rewind() {
    reset($this->_arr);
}

function current() {
    return current($this->_arr);
}

function key() {
    return key($this->_arr);
}

function next() {
    next($this->_arr);
}

function valid() {
    return key($this->_arr) !== null;
}
```

Comment: In a `foreach` loop, I assume this won't return a key - only a numerical representation. Correct?

Comment: @OGHaza thanks. I think his latest edit seems ok to me? My orig code didn't have a bug, but I think I like his latest edit slightly better.

Comment: Excellent solution. Kindly also add count and other functions used in routine

Answer (score 5):

Why not creating an `ArrayObject` from Your associative `Array`? Then You can `getIterator()` from this `ArrayObject` and call `key()`, `next()` etc on it as You want...

Some example:

```
$array = array('one' => 'ONE', 'two' => 'TWO', 'three' = 'THREE');
// create ArrayObject and get it's iterator
$ao = new ArrayObject($my_array);
$it = $ao->getIterator();
// looping
while($it->valid()) {
    echo "Under key {$it->key()} is value {$it->current()}";
    $it->next();
}
```

[ArrayObject](http://php.net/ArrayObject)
[ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.getiterator.php)

Answer (score 2):

http://ideone.com/Fxt0j

```
class myIterator implements Iterator {
    private $position = 0;
    private $keys;

    public function __construct(array $arr) {
        $this->array = $arr;
        $this->keys = array_keys($arr);
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function rewind() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function current() {
        return $this->array[$this->key()];
    }

    function key() {
        return $this->keys[$this->position];
    }

    function next() {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    function valid() {
        return isset($this->keys[$this->position]);
    }
}

$it = new myIterator(array(
        'a' => "firstelement",
        'b' => "secondelement",
        'c' => "lastelement",
    ));

foreach($it as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: This code would be even more useful if it was commented & explained, so others apart from the OP could benefit from your knowledge.

Comment: @Haroon: it only uses basic constructions. If some one could get it - then it is a time to learn the basics

Comment: I really, really don't understand why to still reinvent the wheel... Using ArrayIterator got from ArrayObject that an associative array was turned into is much simpler... And no need to write down our own ArrayIterator...

Comment: This is just a copy of the php.net example

Comment: @Mészáros Lajos: any problems with it? What is your point commenting 2 years old answers?

Comment: I came to this page from google after looking at the php.net example. The problem is taking credit for something that was not written by you. I would recomment mentioning the source, that way it is ok.

The age of a comment is - IMO - irrelevant, useful info is always useful. If you don't want people commenting on your older posts, then, I don't know, delete it.

Comment: @Mészáros Lajos: could you please refer to the page where I took this code almost 2 years ago?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php - Example #1 Basic usage.
Sorry if I made you upset. Why you keep saying 2 years, is it that significant?

Comment: @Mészáros Lajos: I must to disappoint you, but I didn't take the code from that page. I took it from the question. So, I could put the reference to the question itself (very this page) if it makes you happy. Should I do that? PS: If you thoroughly compare the code from my answer and the code from the page you've given a link to you will see there are differences. Not surprising that other parts of code may look similarly (not identically, it's important... for you)

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyItrator implements Iterator 
{
    private $_arr;

    public function __construct(array $arr) 
    {
        $this->_arr = $arr;
    }


    public function rewind()
    {
        reset($this->_arr);
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return current($this->_arr);
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return key($this->_arr);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        next($this->_arr);
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return isset($this->_arr[key($this->_arr)]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it can be as simple as

```
public function current()
{
    return $this->array[array_keys($this->array)[$this->position]];
}

public function next()
{
    ++$this->position;
}

public function key()
{
    return array_keys($this->array)[$this->position];
}

public function valid()
{
    return array_key_exists($this->position, array_keys($this->array)[$this->position]);
}

public function rewind()
{
    $this->position = 0;
}
```

I know a similar answer was posted by @zerkms but imho that doesnt work if the object is already constructed and you have functionality that extends the array